# INNER JOIN with 'OR' condition?

Tags: inner-join, abap, opensql

If have the following coding and the bold marked line is the problem, so it seems to be that's it not possible to use the "OR"-statement within a Inner Join select "ON":

```
PARAMETERS: 
pa_abgrs TYPE vbap-abgrs DEFAULT 'YV0001',  
pa_kokrs TYPE kokrs OBLIGATORY DEFAULT '0002',
pa_monat TYPE bis_abgr_m OBLIGATORY,
pa_gjahr TYPE bis_abgr_j OBLIGATORY.

DATA:   hlp_datum          TYPE sy-datum. 
CONSTANTS: comp_nine(20) TYPE c VALUE '09182736455463728190'.

TYPES: BEGIN OF t_tkkaz_tkkar,
             kateg TYPE kategorie,
             zlnid TYPE dzeilen_id,
             koamk TYPE kstar_mask,          " Kostenart
             zidap TYPE dzeilen_id,          " Zeilen-ID akt.pflichtig
             zidnf TYPE dzlnid_naf,          " Zeilen-ID nicht akt.pfl.
             nafpz TYPE naf_prz,             " nicht akt.f.%-Satz
           END OF t_tkkaz_tkkar.
    DATA: lt_tkkaz_tkkar TYPE TABLE OF t_tkkaz_tkkar.

  CONCATENATE pa_gjahr pa_gjahr INTO hlp_datum.
  TRANSLATE hlp_datum USING comp_nine.

   SELECT tkkar~kateg tkkar~zlnid tkkaz~koamk tkkaz~zidap tkkaz~zidnf       
            tkkaz~nafpz
      FROM tkkar
      INNER JOIN tkkaz
      ON  tkkaz~zidnf = tkkar~zlnid
      OR  tkkaz~zidap = tkkar~zlnid   "<====  THIS LINE
      INTO TABLE lt_tkkaz_tkkar
      WHERE  tkkar~kokrs  = pa_kokrs
      AND    tkkar~versa  = '000'        
      AND    tkkar~abgsl  = pa_abgrs
      AND  ( tkkar~kateg  = 'E'         
      OR     tkkar~kateg  = 'K' )       
      AND   tkkaz~kokrs  = pa_kokrs
      AND    tkkaz~versa  = '000'
      AND    tkkaz~abgsl  = pa_abgrs.
      AND    tkkaz~zglab  GE hlp_datum.

IF sy-subrc = 0.
cl_demo_output=>display( lt_tkkaz_tkkar )
ENDIf.
```

Comment: You have the `CROSS JOIN` alternative, starting from ABAP 7.51. You may indicate any "join" condition in the `WHERE` part.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in ABAP, use [UNION](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapunion.htm) instead. It has the same semantics

```
  SELECT FROM tkkar
         FIELDS tkkar~kateg tkkar~zlnid tkkaz~koamk tkkaz~zidap tkkaz~zidnf tkkaz~nafpz
   INNER JOIN tkkaz
      ON tkkar~zlnid = tkkaz~zidnf
   WHERE ...
  UNION 
 SELECT FROM tkkar
        FIELDS tkkar~kateg tkkar~zlnid tkkaz~koamk tkkaz~zidap tkkaz~zidnf tkkaz~nafpz
  INNER JOIN tkkaz
     ON tkkar~zlnid = tkkaz~zidap
```

Also your query is wrong because you missed the key fields while joining. In fact you don't even need UNION here, you can achieve the same putting OR condition into `WHERE` clause and keeping the other JOIN fields making it more inclusive:

```
SELECT tkkar~kateg tkkar~zlnid tkkaz~koamk tkkaz~zidap tkkaz~zidnf tkkaz~nafpz
  FROM tkkar
 INNER JOIN tkkaz
    ON tkkar~kokrs = tkkaz~kokrs
   AND tkkar~versa = tkkaz~versa
   AND tkkar~abgsl = tkkaz~abgsl
  INTO TABLE lt_tkkaz_tkkar
 WHERE tkkar~kokrs = pa_kokrs
   AND tkkar~versa = '000'
   AND tkkar~abgsl = pa_abgrs
   AND tkkar~kateg IN ('E','K')
   AND tkkaz~zglab GE hlp_datum.
   AND ( tkkar~zlnid = tkkaz~zidnf OR tkkar~zlnid = tkkaz~zidap ).
```